# How to enumerate through a JSON in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

Write a function named `get_y` that takes a JSON formatted string as a parameter in the format of an object with keys `x` and `y` each mapping to an array of integers. Return the `y`-value at `x == -2`.

```
function get_y(json){
    var parse1 = JSON.parse(json);
    for (var it in Array.prototype.entries(parse1['x'])){
        if (parse1[it] == -2){
              return parse1['y'][it];
              }
         }
     }
```

Input:

```
['
  {
    "x": { 1, 2, -2 }, 
    "y": { 0, 2, 4 }
  }
']
```

I am returning a value of zero. Expected output should be 4.

Comment: What is this? `{1, 2, -2}` The curly brackets make it look like an object, but then it doesn't have key/value pairs. Did you mean `[1, 2, -2]`? (ie, an array)?

Comment: It is a JSON string converted to a JSON.

Comment: You take the index of x = -2 of JSON and use that same index to find the value of y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correcting json and accessing proper variables:

```js
function get_y(json){
    var parse1 = JSON.parse(json);
    for (var it in parse1['x']){
        if (parse1['x'][it] == -2){
              return parse1['y'][it];
              }
         }
     }
var result = get_y('{"x":[1,2,-2],"y":[0,2,4]}');
console.log(result);
```